# Ldap query returns null result when deployed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, ldap, ldap-query

I'm using a very simple Ldap query in my asp.net mvc 2.0 site:

String ldapPath = ConfigReader.LdapPath;
            String emailAddress = null;

```
        try
        {

            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ConfigReader.LdapPath);

            search.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(objectSid={0})) ", securityIdentifierValue);

            // add the mail property to the list of props to retrieve                    
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

            var result = search.FindOne();
            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ldap Query with filter:" + search.Filter.ToString() + " returned a null value (no match found)");
            }

            else
            {
                emailAddress = result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException aoorEx)
        {
            throw new Exception( "The query could not find an email for this user.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //_log.Error(string.Format("======!!!!!! ERROR ERROR ERROR !!!!! in LdapLookupUtil.cs getEmailFromLdap Exception: {0}", ex));
            throw ex;
        }
        return emailAddress;
```

It works fine on my localhost machine.   It works fine when I run it in VS2010 on the server.   It always returns a null result when deployed.

Here is my web.config:

Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->

section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->

```
<!--
```

-->
   section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
-->

I'm running it under the default app pool.

Does anybody see the problem?   This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I forgot to add that I have changed the user account running the Default App Pool to a user that has auth to run LDAP queryies.